# How come Netlify CMS on localhost is not working?

Tags: github, hugo, netlify-cms

I’m from Taiwan and not good at English, but I’ll try my best to explain my question.

I use Netlify CMS to build my Hugo website.

Everything runs well, but when I want to change and check if the CMS’s configuration and style is okay, I always need to push my repository to Github, which is disturb me a lot.

So I tried to use `local_backend`: true in `admin/config.yml`, then used this command: `npx netlify-cms-proxy-server`.
then the window showed:

```
info: Netlify CMS File System Proxy Server configured with C:\Users\june.wu\Documents\GitHub\house-blog-hugo-cms
info: Netlify CMS Proxy Server listening on port 8081
```

It looked it ran successfully on localhost:8081.
But when I type localhost:8081 in browser it showed: `Cannot GET /`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Netlify CMS is dead

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm what said in the previous answer. Run `npx netlify-cms-proxy-server` and go to `localhost:8080/admin` or try also `localhost:8080/admin/` (with ending slash). It should work if you are using default `8080` port.

Ignore that CMS is on port 8081 as said in the script log

Answer (score 0):

for anyone looking at this in and still finding it unclear, as said in the docs you need to **go to your regular development server** based on the SSG (static site generator) that you are using once you have **started both the NetlifyCMS and SSG dev servers**. [See point 5 in the beta features docs here](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/beta-features/#working-with-a-local-git-repository).

**You are not supposed to try visit the NetlifyCMS 8081 default port to use the CMS locally.**

I have also seen behaviour mentioned by a few people that it only works with a / at the end of the path. So for example if using Astro as your SSG (which uses the port `:3000` for it's dev server) you should try both:

1. `http://localhost:3000/admin/`
2. `http://localhost:3000/admin`

Although I have been having issues with the NeltlifyCMS dev server with Astro still...